# C# SQL Diagram Builder

Tags: c#, sql, user-interface, gdi+, diagram

I see there are lots of tools out there provide diagram or GUI tool to create SQL script, I have googled alot, but I am not able to find anything on this.

Can anyone guide me on this?

Many Thanks

PlayKid

Comment: What is the question. You see a lot of tools, but you can't find any? I'm confused.

Comment: You want a graphical tool that writes SQL for you? have you tries SQL Server Management Studio Express? you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio Express: http://www.microsoft.com/express/